# Using gridview in an updatepanel and want the link column to fetch correct data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have created my own Application that displays a gridview with several lines. The first column in the grid is a link button. My problem is with the use of the updatepanel functioanlity, since the gridview if not in the update panel works ok, and i can click the link for a line and that line's coulmns are being placed in textboxes below outside the gridview. This is done with a selectedindexchange function.

However when adding:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1" UpdateMode="always" >
        <ContentTemplate>
--gridview code--
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

it wont do any action as before. I have no idea why. My code that is run basically for the post to the text boxes are like this:

```
Protected Sub allCases_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = allCases.SelectedRow
        txtcase.Text = row.Cells(1).Text()
        txtsub.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblsubName"), Label).Text
        txtuser.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lbluserName"), Label).Text
        oDato.Text = row.Cells(9).Text
        lDato.Text = "Case closed!"

        txttype.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseType"), Label).Text
        txtregBy.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseRegby"), Label).Text
        txttopic.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseTopic"), Label).Text
        txtDesc.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseDesc"), Label).Text
        txtSolu.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseSolu"), Label).Text
        'lblinfo.Text = row.Cells(6).Text
        End Sub
```

I suspect it to be becasue of some reload of the page or something like that, but have really no idea. Any help here would be very appreciated.

If you need to see more of the code, let me know.

Comment: Are the textboxes inside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: no. they are outside, and they are not in a second update panel either.

Comment: Try moving them into the same update panel with the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me to the right place Mason! It helped putting everything in the update panel including the textboxes. Now it Works.